# Pyspark - Using map function to populate a dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, dictionary, pyspark

My first post:
I'm trying to create a Dictionary of ingredients with the value being a SparseVector where location of ones correspond to recipes that use that ingredient.

I have a dataframe converted to a rdd...
`rddData = data.rdd.map(list).zipWithIndex()`

One line of the rdd looks like this

```
([426.0,
   [u'Sandwich',
    u'Bean',
    u'Fruit',
    u'Tomato',
    u'turkey',
    u'Vegetable',
    u'Kid-Friendly',
    u'Apple',
    u'Lentil',
    u'Lettuce',
    u'Cookie'],
   u'2006-09-01T04:00:00.000Z',
   None,
   [u'1. Place the stock, lentils, celery, carrot, thyme, and salt in a medium saucepan and bring to a boil. Reduce heat to low and simmer until the lentils are tender, about 30 minutes, depending on the lentils. (If they begin to dry out, add water as needed.) Remove and discard the thyme. Drain and transfer the mixture to a bowl; let cool.',
    u'2. Fold in the tomato, apple, lemon juice, and olive oil. Season with the pepper.',
    u'3. To assemble a wrap, place 1 lavash sheet on a clean work surface. Spread some of the lentil mixture on the end nearest you, leaving a 1-inch border. Top with several slices of turkey, then some of the lettuce. Roll up the lavash, slice crosswise, and serve. If using tortillas, spread the lentils in the center, top with the turkey and lettuce, and fold up the bottom, left side, and right side before rolling away from you.'],
   7.0,
   [u'kosher salt', u'extravirgin olive oil'],
   30.0,
   2.5,
   559.0,
   u'Lentil, Apple, and Turkey Wrap '],
  0)
```

Here, kosher salt and extravirgin olive oil are the ingredients which is the only part of the data I'm currently concerned with.
I've created a dictionary of all unique ingredients by doing

```
ingrList = data.rdd.flatMap(lambda x : x[6]).distinct().collect()
for item in ingrList:
    ingr[item] =[[],[]]
```

The first array is going to be the index of the recipe and the second is the value which is just 1
I made a map function thats supposed to append values to each of these, but when using

```
def mapIngr(recipe):
    for item in recipe[0][6]:  # this is the list of ingredients
        ingr[item][0].append(recipe[1])  # recipe[1] is the index of the recipe 
        ingr[item][1].append(1)
    return recipe
rddData.map(mapIngr)
```

Nothing happens.  I've tested the function with a single line and it works, but when mapping the entire rdd, the dictionary isn't populated.

The goal is to take the two arrays of the value and create a SparseVector after I have all the indices of which recipes each ingredient is in. Not sure if there is a better approach.

Comment: can you add an example of expected result?